Mongodb error handling nodejs. Mongoclient ignores timeout completley
I am trying to use mongodb and have experienced some issues.
If mongod service is stopped, i expect the db to not be able to connect and throw an error, even though i've set the idle params to a very low time (1 sec) it still takes a looong while before it errors out. here's my code:
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
require('dotenv').config()

const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
    connectTimeoutMS: 1000,
    socketTimeoutMS: 1000,    
});

async function get() {
    try {
        await client.db("admin").collections()
        return client;
    } catch (e) {
        throw e;
    }
}

module.exports = { get };

I have awaited client collections to make sure the db tries to do an operation.
here's my main function:
require('dotenv').config()
const db = require('./db/db')
async function exit_program() {
  try {
    const client = await db.get()
    await client.close()
    console.log("shouldn't get here")
    process.exit(0)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}

exit_program()

the shouldn't get here message gets printed if i just return the client without await or anything
my mongodb is on localhost just connect reguarly with mongodb://localhost:27017
so in essence i want to test the connection and if it can't connect to exit and error. this is not happening.

serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 1000
is the needed option
